# jump to another page and transer data to it at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers

In the homepage of the site I'm working on, I want to have a photo of an actual place and above it a button named "See more"

The button, when clicked , transfers the user to another page where he can find an openlayers map with the spatial point of the place already rendered on the map.

Now, to implement this I need to transfer the name of the place from the homepage to the map page, when the button is clicked and immediately call a javascript function, in order to have openlayers render the point on the map

How do I do this?

Transfer data and immediately call a javascript function ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could simply provide it as a query string in the request

Comment: You can use HTML5 localStorage to transfer these. Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @johan I just edited the question. Sorry for last-minute editing. Thanks.

Comment: @MaximErshov - unless this is meant to be semi-permanent state on the client across many pages, a query parameter would be more appropriate than local storage because the query parameter is targeted at a particular page.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to do this would be to add a query parameter to the galleries page URL before you open it like this:

```
/galleries?placeID=3456
```

Then, you can access that `placeID` either on the server or in the galleries page javascript (whichever you want).

---

In the galleries page, you would then have some javascript that runs when the page is initialized.  That javascript would examine the query parameters on the URL and act accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // examine window.location.search here to look at the query parameters
    var matches = window.location.search.match(/placeID=(.*?)(&|$)/);
    if (matches) {
        var placeID = matches[1];
        // do whatever you want with placeID here
    }
});
```

Comment: I just edited the question. Sorry for last-minute editing. Thanks.

Comment: @user2860857 - I added more to my answer.

Comment: Interesting. But I never done it before. Can you be more specific or point me to a tutorial? Thanks again

Comment: @user2860857 - You haven't shown us your HTML, but if you have a unique button for each place (which your description sounds like), then you can just put the query parameter right into the URL that each button fires.  Nothing special to do in the homepage beyond that.  In the galleries page, I have code in my answer for that.